# CMAKE can't find OpenNI

Tags: cmake, rgb, kinect, openni

I’ve been trying to run the “tutorial to get started” with the Kinect libraries (http://nicolas.burrus.name/index.php/Research/KinectUseNestk) but I stumbled across an error.

When I try the following line in the CLI:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo ..
```

I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at D:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHan
dleStandardArgs.cmake:91 (MESSAGE):
Could NOT find OpenNI (missing: OPENNI_LIBRARY OPENNI_INCLUDE_DIR)

Call Stack (most recent call first):
D:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardAr
gs.cmake:252 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
nestk/cmake/FindOpenNI.cmake:51 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
nestk/cmake/find_nestk_deps.cmake:77 (FIND_PACKAGE)
build/nestk/UseEmbeddedNestk.cmake:23 (INCLUDE)
nestk/CMakeLists.txt:67 (INCLUDE)
```

Does anyone have any idea how I have to solve this? I’ve installed OpenNI, it’s installed at D:\Program Files\OpenNI.

Answer (score 6):

For biulding an OpenNI project with CMAKE you can wirte this in your cmakelists. It works fine. (I also included NITE2, but if you don't needed just delete those lines).

```
OPTION (ENABLE_OPENNI2_NITE2 ON)

IF( ENABLE_OPENNI2_NITE2 )
set(OPENNI2_DEFINITIONS ${PC_OPENNI_CFLAGS_OTHER})
FIND_LIBRARY( OPENNI2_LIBRARY
             NAMES OpenNI2
             HINTS ${PC_OPENNI2_LIBDIR} ${PC_OPENNI2_LIBRARY_DIRS} /usr/lib
             PATHS "$ENV{PROGRAMFILES}/OpenNI2/Lib${OPENNI2_SUFFIX}" "$ENV{PROGRAMW6432}/OpenNI2/Lib${OPENNI2_SUFFIX}" "$ENV{PROGRAMW6432}/OpenNI2"
             PATH_SUFFIXES lib lib64
)
FIND_PATH( OPENNI2_INCLUDE_DIR OpenNI.h
          HINTS ${PC_OPENNI2_INCLUDEDIR} ${PC_OPENNI2_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
                  /usr/include/openni2 /usr/include/ni2
                  PATHS "$ENV{PROGRAMFILES}/OpenNI2/include" "$ENV{PROGRAMW6432}/OpenNI2/include"
          PATH_SUFFIXES openni2 ni2)

FIND_LIBRARY( NITE2_LIBRARY
             NAMES NiTE2
             HINTS ${PC_OPENNI2_LIBDIR} ${PC_OPENNI2_LIBRARY_DIRS} /usr/lib
             PATHS "$ENV{PROGRAMFILES}/PrimeSense/NiTE2/lib${OPENNI2_SUFFIX}" "$ENV{PROGRAMW6432}/PrimeSense/NiTE2/lib${OPENNI2_SUFFIX}"
             PATH_SUFFIXES lib
)
FIND_PATH( NITE2_INCLUDE_DIR NiTE.h
          HINTS ${PC_OPENNI2_INCLUDEDIR} ${PC_OPENNI2_INCLUDE_DIRS} /usr/include/openni2 /usr/include/nite2
          PATHS "$ENV{PROGRAMFILES}/PrimeSense/NiTE2/include" "$ENV{PROGRAMW6432}/PrimeSense/NiTE2/include"
          PATH_SUFFIXES openni2         
)
ENDIF( ENABLE_OPENNI2_NITE2 )
```

And later you need to link the directories and libs found:

```
link_directories( ${OPENNI2_LIBRARY} ${NITE2_LIBRARY} )
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${OPENNI2_INCLUDE_DIR} ${NITE2_INCLUDE_DIR} )
target_link_libraries( project ${OPENNI2_LIBRARY} ${NITE2_LIBRARY} )
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try to modify the CMakeLists.txt file and add or modify the following lines

```
set(OPENNI_INCLUDE_DIR "D:/Program Files/OpenNI/Include")
set(OPENNI_LIB_DIR "D:/Program Files/OpenNI/Lib")
```

Otherwise, look for a file named CMakeCache.txt inside the binaries folder. Look for  OPENNI_INCLUDE_DIR and OPENNI_LIB_DIR, set the right path, and run cmake again.

If none of those work, and you can run cmake-gui, try to use it instead of the cli command and manually specify those paths in the GUI.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure OPEN_NI_BIN, OPEN_NI_INCLUDE, OPEN_NI_INSTALL_PATH environment variables are all set and that they point to the right place, because the cmake module that checks for OPEN_NI checks those values.
I was getting the same error, but in my case, it was a problem mixing 64 and 32 bit libraries. I was building opencv with 32 bit compilers, but OpenNI was 64 bit. So I uninstalled all 64bit and left only 32 bit versions, which made it work.

Kind regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Typical openni2 distribution has following file /OpenNI-Linux-Arm-2.2/OpenNIDevEnvironment

It has described all necessary variables to compile and link:

```
export OPENNI2_INCLUDE=/opt/cbox/OpenNI-Linux-Arm-2.2/Include
export OPENNI2_REDIST=/opt/cbox/OpenNI-Linux-Arm-2.2/Redist
```

So you need to export these variables and then run the cmake with OpenNI2 enabled:

```
$export OPENNI2_INCLUDE=/opt/cbox/OpenNI-Linux-Arm-2.2/Include
$export OPENNI2_REDIST=/opt/cbox/OpenNI-Linux-Arm-2.2/Redist
$cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_OPENNI2=ON  ..
```

Somewhere in cmake result you should see:

--     OpenNI2:                     YES (ver 2.2.0, build 33)